# pam/openssh disable ssh for a user but leave scp intact?

Tags: ssh, scp, pam

I've set up a user. I'm using `pam_chroot.so` in pam so that they are chrooted to a directory. They can currently `ssh` and `scp` to that location. How can I disable `ssh` for that user?

Comment: You'll find it much easier to restrict them to SFTP than SCP.

Comment: @Kenster I wish I could, unfortunately it is not possible for what we need to do. Thanks.